# Two network interfaces. Specifying one for inbound RDP, another for Internet connection

Tags: windows, networking, rdp, internet, connection

I have two network interfaces in my computer.(Adapter 1 and 2)
I want to use adapter #1 only for inbound RDP and use adapter #2 for Internet connection. So if I disable adapter #2, Internet connection should not working. Adapter #1 should not be used for Internet connection (only for inbound RDP) no matter if adapter #2 on or off.
Is it possible to configure Windows that way?

Comment: It seems [this article](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1913106/bind-applications-specific-network-adapter.html) and [this one](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/bind-windows-application-to-specific-network-adapter-with-forcebindip/) might help

Answer (score -1):

You can use the internal firewall of your winfows installation with the advanced settings